# Change comment character in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I am editing the .properties file in notepad++. 
I can toggle the block comment using Cntrl+K but it puts ";" instead of "#".

I modify langs.model.xml file and replaced ";" with "#". I restarted notepad but it is not working.

Does anyone know how can I change the control character in notepad++ for properties file?

Comment: I have a similar problem. (Using npp++ v 5.8.5), Perl. Ctrl-Q and Ctrl-K simply don't work - they do nothing.

Comment: I know this is old, but @HelenCraigman, you have to select a language to have the comment option (comment key depends on language, so if notepad++ don't know what language you are working on, it assume plain text, in which "comment" don't mean anything

Comment: and also, @swd, didn't I solved your issue? you were talking about langs.model.xml, which is an old file from an old version, I gave a solution with langs.xml, do you still have problems? (yeah he asked 4 years ago I know, he probably don't care anymore!)

Comment: sorry lost track of it. :) this helps me today as well

Comment: @Rafiki Apparently, `langs.model.xml` is not an old file, but the factory defaults for the various languages. I would imagine this file is used on first installation, and whenever a new user is created on the machine.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

My issue was with VB, NotePad++ don't have the right symbol set (REM instead of ')
I don't want to change the language, since the hilighting of keyword would be wrong
I found this on [mysysadmintips](http://www.mysysadmintips.com/windows/clients/436-change-comment-character-in-notepad) :

> Luckily it's pretty easy to modify comment marks for various languages
>   in Notepad++
>
> ```
> Open Notepad++ language config file:
> C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\langs.xml
> Scroll down to  <Language name="vb" ext="vb vbs" (or other depending on what language you want to modify)
> Change commentLine="REM" to commentLine="'" 
> Restart Notepad++
> ```

Comment: Thank you I totally looked for this one

Comment: In case you use cloud settings, you have to modify the langs.xml there too. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28050274/changing-comment-line-character-in-notepad-langs-xml-doesnt-work

Answer (score 2):

You can get the behavior by using a different language. Perl, PowerShell, Python, Ruby, and Shell will use the `#` for comments.

Then simply select the block you want to comment on/off and press:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> (which will toggle comments)

Comment: Yes that work around I am also using.. first change the language to python and then press shift+k to comment and shift+cntrl+k to uncomment.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the difference is however I changed both the langs.xml & the langs.model.xml
& ^+Q toggles the block.

(Specifically I wanted to replace batch files "REM" with "::")