# Altering Notepad++ Block/Stream comment functionality

Tags: notepad++, comments

Is there any way to change the way Comment/Uncomment menu commands work in notepad++
per language.
I want the php comment function to be able to do `<?php /*  */ ?>` instead of just `/* */`

Comment: Your question is a similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147813/change-comment-character-in-notepad which has no answers yet :(

Comment: `/* */` comments are meant to be used within PHP blocks anyway. You shouldn't have to add the opening and closing PHP tags. Not to mention there are a dozen other languages that use the same style of comments.

Comment: i have a php file with open html in it and i need to comment out the html so it does not go trough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a user defined comment block. On the picture menu there is a dialogue window with a lightning bolt hover over it it says user defined dialogue click it. Click Comment and Number tab header and edit stream and/or block comment.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can or rather *should* change the basic language syntax.

I believe Notepad++ is just following the language specification.